# Access Violation Exception (5) in function of injected DLL

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, bitmap, code-injection

I am extending the functionality of a Windows component using code injection. I overwrite a method's instructions, calling my own method that does the job of the original one. Let's say we have:

```
void Target(HDC magic123)
{ ... }
```

Below are the first few instructions of the method:

```
push    rbx //
push    rbp // stores registers to recover later
...
sub     rsp, 0x260 // for all 7 pushes
...
mov     r12, [rsp+0x28] // stores a pointer to 'magic123'
...
...a lot more instructions
```

---

Immediately after `mov r12, [rsp+0x28]`, I overwrite the next instructions with:

```
mov rcx, r12                // 1st parameter to pass to a called function goes in RCX
add rsp, 0x260              // restore the stack
push 0                      // create shadow space |EDIT: MISALIGNED STACK. WRONG.
mov rax, &DetouredFunction  // function in my injected DLL
call rax                    // call it with the HDC as parameter
```

My function in the DLL:

```
void DetouredFunction(uintptr_t hdcPointer)
{
uintptr_t hdcAddress = *(uintptr_t*)(hdcPointer); // convert pointer to address
HDC hdc = (HDC)hdcAddress; // create a HDC from the address


HBITMAP hBitmapWallpaper = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SelectObject(hdc, hBitmapWallpaper);
}
```

Everything works until I reach a call to 'LoadImage' in my injected DLL's function. It throws an 'Access Violation Exception (5)' trying to read a non-existing address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

What is the problem? Please correct any of my comments above if they contain mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: You also need to restore the saved registers from the stack. Also, why do you `call` instead of `jmp`? Seems you want to jump, and that has the added benefit of not messing up required stack alignment which may then cause your fault ;) It's also unclear how you converted `HDC` to a pointer. From here it looks like you should just overwrite the very first instruction with a `jmp` to your function and that's that.

Comment: @Jester I am aware of that, but my function doesn't even reach its return, so messed up registers are not a problem. The `HDC` is passed to the original function as a parameter and I want to pass  the same `HDC` to my own function that should serve as a replacement.

Comment: But stack alignment and missing shadow space could be.

Comment: @Jester Why would my function care about the registers or stack values of previous functions? I know that they will be overwritten and those original functions will mess up, but I don't see how it could be a problem for my function.

Comment: Because calling conventions require specific stack alignments.

Comment: I talked with @Jester in IM and I was indeed misaligning the stack. He told me why it matters and how to fix it. Thank you for all the responses!

Comment: i inject lots of code and they works fine. but i don't understand your code injection. why you add rsp.0x260? and why you push 0? you shouldn't add stack pointer (rsp) and you should push address of your hdcPointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was misaligning the stack. It did not have any evident effect until another call to LoadImage was made.